# How can I smoothly connect this cylinder shape with a torus ? Including half pipes and a curve from back of cylinder to torus (see side view)

Tags: topology

I am trying to model the object you can see in the reference photos.

Back view:

[image: Back]

Side view

[image: Side]

Front View
[image: Front]

Top View:
[image: Top]

Bottom view:
[image: bottom]

Angled View:

[image]

I am having great difficulties smoothly connecting this cylinder shape with the torrus shape. As you can see it has "half pipes" going from the sides to the ring. But it also curves from the backside of the cylinder (which juts out/stands out farther than the end of the torus) to the torus. So you have different curves that have to be connected smoothly. This also means that the cylinder shape somewhat "dissolves" at the bottom when it meets the torus. I tried with bridge edge loops that go from torus to top of the cylinder (see blender file). However then I am left with trying to bridge the sides with back and front parts which I dont manage for the back part (without creating a unsmooth mess of it). Also you lose the shape of the object in side view.

Any ideas with this modelling problem? How do I smoothly connect the cylinder with the torus as seen in the refrence photos with all the curves shown (half pipe on side, curve from back of cylinder to the back of torus on the backside)?

[image]

Comment: No link to the .blend?

Comment: You need to pack your reference photos in your blend file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a 24/8 segment torus (use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in *Edit* mode in order to shrink/fatten to make it as thick as your reference, cut a hole:

[image]

[image]

Extrude inwards, right click > *LoopTools > Circle*, still use the side view to make sure that it fits the shape:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Use the front view to correct:

[image]

Add some edge loops if necessary, etc:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks can you show me how it would work with the backside of the cylinder jutting out farther than the backside of the torrus. I have added another reference image to my post.

Comment: you just need to increase the radius of the circle, create some new edge loops and move them back, etc. Try to keep as less edge loops as possible to make the shape easier to work

Comment: Yes I am new to blender.stackexchange. Sorry for that. I have added the side view in my post.

Comment: Ok I've edited, please check the answer

Comment: Thanks. That looks good. How does your model look from the front?

Comment: Ok I've corrected with the help of the front view

Comment: Thank you for your generous help. Can you tell me how to extrude inwards? Whats the shortcut? And for Right click circle, do I need a add on?

Comment: delete the vertices, select the edge all around the hole, press E to extrude then Enter right away, then scale inwards (S). For the Circle operation you need to activate the LoopTools addon which is part of Blender

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135293/discussion-between-paul-and-moonboots).

Answer (score 4):

Here's the simple version:

- Create a Torus
- Go to edit mode.
- Pick a vertex on the top ring and delete it.
- Pick the 8 vertices that surround the hole.
  [image: selected vertices]
- Scale 0 on the Z axis
- Use loop tools to form into a circle.
- Extrude on the Z axis.
- Add a subsurf
  [image: final form]

Loop tools is an add-on that's built in and you have to enable.  Your blend file has it enabled.

Comment: Sorry thats not how the object looks. For some reason my blender file didnt upload? Its a torus and the the cylinder shape sits on the ring.

Comment: Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, please add enough images to your post to make it clear what your object looks like

Comment: @Marty I have added the blender file. I could only upload one image per this software but more reference photos are in the blend file.

Comment: @Paul I've edited my answer.  I would hope that you accept mine and then upvote Moonboots' similar but different take.

Comment: @Marty please check another reference image (side view). Problem I have with the answers so far is that the cylinder backside does not jut out versus end of backside of torus. As you can see from the reference image the backside of the cylinder juts out father than the backside of the torus. And then there is a smooth curve connecting backside of cylinder to backside of torus.

Comment: @Paul your current file doesn't contain the reference images.

Comment: @Marty I have also added front view. Is it possible to create this specific shape with the tools you mentioned?

Comment: @Paul It is.  You can extrude the cylinder a short distance, rotate it and scale it to get it off center and at an angle, extrude it again, and get it to match, as moonboots has done in their answer.  The two answers are very similar.