# Why is my topology messed up compared to object I am trying to model? How to fix this?

Tags: topology

I implented the generous tips you gave as a reply to this question: [How can I smoothly connect this cylinder shape with a torus ? Including half pipes and a curve from back of cylinder to torus (see side view)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259441/how-can-i-smoothly-connect-this-cylinder-shape-with-a-torus-including-half-pip)

However now I am stuck again, as I am not able to copy the smooth edge flow of the object. Maybe my dimensions are a bit off (I am not modelling with the pictures in the background as they dont fit together, are slightly distorted) and thats one reason. However I think there might be other problems too.

Here is what I am talking about (for reference photos without my drawings check other question). Please check my **blender file** to see my edge flow in edit mode.

**Smooth Edge flow Front of object:**

[image: Smooth Edge Flow Front]

**Squarish/unsmooth edge flow Front of my model (also pinching in the transition):**

[image: Squarish/unsmooth edge flow Front my model here]

**Smooth Edge Flow side with nice curve:**

[image: Smooth Edge Flow side]

Unsmooth Side view my model only little curving effect.

[image: Unsmooth side, little curving effect]

**Smooth but nicely defined back (with cylinder outline still visible):**

[image]

**Very squarish back of my model:**

[image]

One more tidbit: I asked **Ian McGlasham** how one might model this (you should guys should check out his really nice youtube chanel, he is a pro). And he had this to say (sadly I am not exactly sure what he means). Maybe you guys know what he meant:

*"You would create the basic topology by deleting a square of faces on your torus (maybe 4x4) extruding and scaling the remaining loop in slightly and moving it up in z. extrude another one or two loops up using the circle tool from looptools  ( perhaps setting the influence to around 20% for the first loop, 50% for the second and increase that gradually until it is your cylindrical shape. This would just be your basic topology. Create a vertex group out of all of the "new geometry you have made and place your target cylinder shape inside it. add a shrinkwrap to the torus (project mode, tick the negative checkbox too.) Select the cylinder as the target and the vertex group as the..er.. vertex group! that makes it sound easy but you will constantly be damaging your topology so you will need to be going back and forwards using the circle tool and scaling loops to zero along their z axis. fiddly but fun! Hope that helps - I'll make a video about it at some point!
edit: Moving the loops and faces along their normals or custom transform pivots will save you lots of continuity errors as loops move out of their natural planes."*

Any tips you can give me would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it's almost good, from now there's no magic solution, you just need to add at least one edge loop on your cylinder and move some edges and vertices in order to keep the faces round, avoid pinching etc.

For the profile I would add one loopcut and pull some of its vertices to the left with the *Proportional Editing* option activated:

[image]

Also pull all these vertices in order to round the back a bit:

[image]

And scale these edges a bit on Y:

[image]

For the front view, keep the *Proportional Editing* activated, select these vertices and pull them to the left:

[image]

Slide this edge a bit with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>:

[image]

Also pull these vertices forward to avoid the hollow:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi moonboots, Thanks for the answer. I really like your solution for the back part (I just tried it out myself and its very good). For the front part I think its not quite there yet. I think for the front part the edge flow need to be redirected. If you look closely at the front view, there is actually a tiny change of texture/ a tiny cut. Its a longish vertical rectangle and then you have smooth edge flow around it (i.e. that goes directly into the ring).

Comment: Oh ok I didn't see that, I thought it was the reflection

Comment: One more thing I noticed for the back actually. At the bottom of the back it has a bit more circular momentum (for a lack of a better term) than what we have in our models I think (see indicated white line I drew on model). In our models the edge flow at the bottom goes too soon horizontal. I think with clever changing of the edge flow I might get even closer to the model. I will try it out.

Comment: Without the real object and with only photos it's hard to guess what are the real shapes, but as I said I don't think there's any magic trick, you need to push and pull some vertices, sometimes enable the Proportional Editing option so that it deforms nicely, and only add an edge loop it the current topology is not enough for the shape you're trying to model, a too dense topology makes it harder to model